# How to include a Custom field into Audit.EntityFramework?

Tags: .net-core, audit, audit.net

I'm using Audit.EntityFramework.Core, where I implement Auditing by Using DbContextHelper,IAuditDbContext and Overriding SaveChanges() and SaveChangesAsync() methods, **Instead of inheriting AuditDbContext**.

```
public partial class MyContext: DbContext
{
    private static DbContextHelper _helper = new DbContextHelper();
    private readonly IAuditDbContext _auditContext;

    public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options) : base(options)
    {
        _auditContext = new DefaultAuditContext(this);
        _helper.SetConfig(_auditContext);
    }

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        return _helper.SaveChanges(_auditContext, () => base.SaveChanges());
    }

    public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        return await _helper.SaveChangesAsync(_auditContext, () => base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken));
    }
}
```

> **My requirement is to add some custom field to Audit**

, but since I don't inherit AuditDbContext I don't have the access to `context.AddAuditCustomField("key", object);`

I tried to manually add the implementation of AddAuditCustomField(), but I couldn't figure out the link between evt.CustomFields["sample"] and ExtraFields["sample"].

```
_context.AddAuditCustomField("Sample", sample);
```

`

```
a.RequesterID = evt.CustomFields["Sample"] as string;
```

I'm new to this Library, so kindly help me out. Thank you.

Comment: @thepirat000 - I looked into some previous stackoverflow questions as well as Github documentation. But I didn't find the solution for my requirement correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: `ExtraFields` is a property on `AuditDbContext` (and also on `DefaultAuditContext`) that temporarily stores the fields to be added as custom fields to the scope once you call the DbContext's `SaveChanges`. So you should be able to use the `ExtraFields` on your `_auditContext`. Could you clarify what are you trying to add and which data provider are you using?

Comment: @thepirat000 I'm using EntityFramework as the dataprovider and I want to store the reference to the parent entity of the audited entity into a column of audit table.

Comment: Basically I'm mapping several entity into a single audit table. For some report generation purpose I want to store the reference to the parent entity of the audited entity

Comment: @thepirat000 it would be great will you also maintain a blog in order to support this library. It will be really helpful for the people who are heading to this Audit.Entityframework for the first time. I'm also planning to write some blog about the usage of Audit.Entityframework once I got some proficiency on it

Comment: I don't have time to maintain a blog, sorry but I would be happy if you, or anyone else do. Also I think you should open a new Issue on GitHub for following up on this one. I guess the parent entity ID *is* part of your audited entity, so I don't think you need an extra field for that, but maybe I'm missing something.